# Replace a substring with two different strings depending on where they are

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string with some asterisks:

```
myvar = "this is an *italicized* substring"
```

I want to replace `*italicized*` with `{i}italicized{/i}` for the project I'm working on, txt2rpy, but I'm not sure how to have two different substrings being replaced depending on what order they come in.

Comment: Please can you clarify what characters can be in the substring. Should there be any restriction? For example, could you have spaces: `this is a *two word* substring`?

Comment: @alani There's no restrictions regarding what's in the substring, as long as there's not another asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to substitute the pattern as a whole:

```
re.sub(r'\*(.*?)\*', r'{i}\1{/i}', myvar)
```

In the regexp:

- `\*` matches a literal `*` (used twice)
- `(.*?)` matches any number of any (non-newline) characters, as few as possible - it is also in a capture group

In the replacement:

- `{i}` and `{/i}` are literals
- `\1` means to put what was in the first (and in this case, only) capture group

This gives:

```
>>> import re
>>> myvar = "this is an *italicized* substring"
>>> print(re.sub(r'\*(.*?)\*', r'{i}\1{/i}', myvar))
this is an {i}italicized{/i} substring
```

If you have more than one occurrence of the pattern, that will work also:

```
myvar = "this is an *italicized* substring, and here is *another* one"
```

will give

```
this is an {i}italicized{/i} substring, and here is {i}another{/i} one
```

Comment: Huh, I guess I forgot that ```{i}``` and ```{/i}``` are both tags in Python. I should know this, considering I'm using it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlienMeepers I am not sure what you mean by "tags". When I say that they are literals, I mean that they are simply values that are used in the replacement without any special meaning as far as `re.sub` is concerned (as is generally the case with the replacement part - the `\1` is special).

Comment: I'm using Ren'Py to make a mod for DDLC, and this code is used for a conversion tool I'm making. {i} and {/i} are italics tags for a string (instead of **)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with capture groups for that:

```py
import re

txt = "this is an *italicized* substring"

res = re.sub(r"\*([^*]+)\*", "{i}\g<1>{/i}", txt)
```

will have `res` as:

```
this is an {i}italicized{/i} substring
```

---

This pattern is pretty basic: It matches a literal `*`, then character **not** an asterisk, then another literal `*`. The main point here is that we use a capture group to catch the word part.

Then we simply substitute the full match with the word we saved (accessed by `\g<1>`) surrounded with your wanted characters.

---

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/j3sxRo/2)

Answer (score -1):

Create a loop for parsing and keep a counter to track,whenever the counter is even keep the second tag and replace odd ones with first tag.

Answer (score -1):

you could you use a for loop and say

```
myvar = "this is an *italicized* substring"
positions = []
for x in range(len(myvar)):
    if myvar[x] == "*":
       positions.append(x)
inAsteriks = myvar[0:positions[0]] + "{i}" + myvar[positions[0]+1:positions[1]] + "{/i}" + myvar[positions[0]+1:]
```

Comment: inAsteriks = myvar[0:positions[0]] + {i} + myvar[positions[0]+1:positions[1]] + {/i} + myvar[positions[0]+1:]
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: \ has inherent meaning, put {i} and {\i} in quotations